# How to copy 32 bytes at a time to an array

Tags: c

I have a struct as follows, which has a pointer and a length, I want to copy `mydata` in terms of 32 bytes at a time to an array of 32 bytes, not sure what is the correct way to do it

```
typedef struct{
  void * ptr;
  size_t len;
}buf;

const uint8_t mydata[] =  {0x43, 0x54, 0x09, 0x32, 0x41, 0x45, 0x67, 0x78, 
                            0x81, 0x74, 0x67, 0x78, 0x43, 0x54, 0x09, 0x32, 
                            0x41, 0x45, 0x67, 0x78, 0x81, 0x74, 0x67, 0x78,
                            0x43, 0x54, 0x09, 0x32, 0x41, 0x45, 0x67, 0x78,
                            0x43, 0x54, 0x09, 0x32, 0x41, 0x45, 0x67, 0x78,
                            0x81, 0x74, 0x67, 0x78, 0x43, 0x54, 0x09, 0x32,
                            0x41, 0x45, 0x67, 0x78, 0x81, 0x74, 0x67, 0x78, 
                            0x43, 0x54, 0x09, 0x32, 0x41, 0x45, 0x67, 0x78};

const buf mybuf = {mydata, sizeof(mydata)};

int myfunc(buf mybuf){
   if(mybuf.len % 32 != 0){
    return -1; //checking if it is a multiple of 32 bytes
   }
   int no_myBufBytes = mybuf.len / 32; // getting how many set of 32 bytes are available

  uint8_t bytes32data[2][32]; // creating an array of 32 bytes
  for(int i = 0; i < no_myBufBytes ; i++){
   bytes32data[i][32] = mybuf.ptr + 32; // copying 32 bytes at a time
   mybuf.ptr = mybuf.ptr + 32; // moving the pointer to 32 bytes
  }
}
```

Comment: Why not `memcpy`?

Comment: Copying 32byte in a single (processor) operation would require a very special architecture. Doing it in one C operation can be done with memcpy.

Comment: 32-bits at a time is possible, if suboptimal on 64-bit platforms. 32 bytes is not something you can do in one cycle, it's impossible since there's not enough memory bandwidth for that on any platform I've heard of. You can usually get 64 to 128 bits per cycle under optimal circumstances, typically less since the memory frequency is often two or three times slower than the CPU itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is the best you will do.

```
void CopyChunks( uint8_t* dest, const uint8_t* src, unsigned int num )
{
    assert((((uint32_t)src)&3)==0); // data must be 32-bit aligned
    assert((((uint32_t)dest)&3)==0); // data must be 32-bit aligned

    uint32_t* d=(uint32_t*)dest;
    uint32_t* s=(uint32_t*)src;
    while( num-- )
    {
        // copy 32 bytes
        *d++=*s++;
        *d++=*s++;
        *d++=*s++;
        *d++=*s++;
        *d++=*s++;
        *d++=*s++;
        *d++=*s++;
        *d++=*s++;
    }
}
```

Of course this assumes a 32-bit architecture. A 64-bit version is a trivial adaptation.

Comment: What if `src` and `dest` aren't 32 bit aligned?

Comment: I am guessing that the user will encounter a problem, the exact nature of which will depend on their compiler, and will go on to address it.

Comment: They did. That's why they are here for help. Giving them buggy code is not the way to go.

Comment: @cleblanc What do you think will happen, and how would you address it? Do you still think there is something lacking in this answer?

Comment: @ikegami I think you may have misread the OP. They didn't encounter an issue to do with data alignment. Please let me know if you think this code is still "buggy"

Comment: @TimRandall I see now that you've added asserts at the top of the function which is good.  That's the right Idea, you would copy bytes until the source is aligned and then you can copy `uint32_t`s until it's time to copy the remaining bytes.

Comment: @cleblanc I was under the impression that the OP wanted something high-performance, which I understood to imply that the data would be aligned. I suspect that, if we attempt to provide a solution for the general case, we will end up reinventing the `memcpy`

Comment: @TimRandall OP is probably best off using `memcpy`.  Most times `memcpy` is not what needs optimization in the code.

Comment: Re "*They didn't encounter an issue to do with data alignment.*", I never said otherwise. /// Re "*Please let me know if you think this code is still "buggy"*", Take your pick: Buggy, or doesn't meet the OP's needs (as far as we know).